# Linux make file: How to exit for loop early with error message

Tags: linux, for-loop, gnu-make

I am setting up a makefile to run a test that involves diffing a list of generated files against their counterparts in a master directory.  I can get the loop to work and to exit if the diff fails but I haven't figured out how to include a failure message and still exit the for loop (and the make process) immediately.

Here is the core of what I have:

```
OUTFILE = $(patsubst $(MASTER_DIR1)/%,$(OUTDIR1)/%,$$file)

default: test

$(OUTDIR1):
    $(MKDIR) $(OUTDIR1)

test: $(OUTDIR)
    @for file in $(MASTER_LIST1); do \
        echo $$file; \
        diff $(IGNORE_OPT) \
        $$file \
        $(OUTFILE) \
        && exit 1; \
    done
```

This exits on fail but doesn't inform the user as to why. I tried changing the `&& exit 1;` line to:

```
&& (echo "Diff failed"; exit 1; ); \
```

That displayed the error message but no longer exited.

How do I add an error message and still exit right away?

TIA!

Comment: Use `{ ...; }` instead of `(...)`. `()` is a sub-shell and your exit gets swallowed. That being said you don't need to use a shell loop for this. You can let make do it all (by creating targets for each test pair possibly even with just a single pattern rule) and then failures just cause make to stop.

Comment: @Etan-Reisner - does the {..} usage that you desribe apply in the middle of the long for-loop command? When I use `&& {echo "Diff failed" || exit 1; };` gnumake complains about unexpected token `}'.

Comment: Notice the spacing in my example blocks. The leading space after `{` is important as is the trailing `; ` before the `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the help provided by Etan Reisner in his comment to the original question, this is the solution that worked:

```
test: $(OUTDIR)
    @for file in $(MASTER_LIST1); do \
        echo $$file; \
        diff $(IGNORE_OPT) \
        $$file \
        $(OUTFILE) \
        && { echo "Diff failed"; exit 1; }; \
    done
```